# Customised Print using Javascript/JQuery with print commands and settings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Is it possible to print a WebPage or Document in JS in a customised way?
I think yes. But how?
Even though I don't know how to, Lemme tell you that it's possible:

> Google Chrome does pop-up a window, perhaps a Modal Window that has
>   customization of the settings.

[image]
 Maybe it sends that data like:

```
print(){

printer: MJF-2245;
paper: letter;
margins: none;
headers: false;
fooetrs:false;

}
```

If that's not possible how is Chrome doing? If not using JS, what's it?

Any Great Minds over there have any ideas?

Please feel free. At least leave a comment on what you feel. Achieveable?

Comment: Remember that all browsers are also native applications on the OS, so they have native compiled code that can do a lot more than JavaScript. Presumably they use some native code to open this window. However, it is worth noting that the print window that pops up is, in fact, an HTML page, as you can open a dev tools window (try right-clicking and selecting `Inspect Element`) that is connected directly to that print window (and not to the parent page!). My guess is Chrome just uses HTML as the means to view this window, and it is a special window integrating with native code.

Comment: @ajp15243, Thanks hope so. Maybe Future Programming languages let us more!